# How Can we have Multi Versioned Angular Libraries in NX Monorepo

Tags: angular, versioning, nrwl-nx, angular-library, nrwl

We are using NX as our monorepo tool, Our repo contains 4 different angular apps.

Directory Structure:-

```
.
└── apps/
    ├── app-1/
    │   └── header-component
    ├── app-2/
    │   └── header-component
    ├── app-3/
    │   └── header-component
    └── app-4/
        └── header-component
```

There are many components and services which are common across all the apps, for example `header-component` , current we are copy pasting the component in each folder which is getting very tedious for us as the number of components are increasing day by day.

So we wanted to use NX library to share common stuffs between our different apps, so we created a library called `common` to keep all the common stuffs and presentational components.

Now our directory structure looks like this:-

```
.
├── apps/
│   ├── app-1
│   ├── app-2
│   ├── app-3
│   └── app-4
└── libs /
    └── common/
        └── header-component
```

Till now we are able to share the common code with the library.

But the problem arises is if we are making some changes in library it is affecting all the apps. and we need to go through all the places where the affected component is used, now if some breaking changes comes into a component it will break few places where the component is used. So we are looking something version kind of thing for the library so that if there is breaking changes then it will be only used in the app it is made for so we want a versioned approach for the library.

Any suggestion or any otherway to handle this is most appreciated.

Till now i was not able to figure out anything to tackel this problem.